# My question = until user press "enter" take average from user inputs in c++

Tags: c++, input, average

This code calculates the average from user that user inputs integer until user inputs "666" integer. However, I want to make it stop when the user just presses the enter key. How can I achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; //s

int main()

{
int total = 0, counter = 0, number, average;

    do
    {


    cin >> number;
    if(number == 666) //what should i do to make enter button instead of 666?
    {
        average = total / counter;
        cout << average;
        return 0;

    }
    total = total + number;
    counter = counter + 1;

} while(1);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have a look at `std::getline`.

Comment: would you edit this again? @super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been found the solution:
note that I use Code::Blocks compiler and I had to make a adjustment.
Settings> compiler > tick on the """have g++ follow the c++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]""" box and click OK. 
solution is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
float c = 0, sum = 0;
string input;
while (true) {
cout << "input number:";
getline(cin,input);
if (input == "") {
cout << "average:" << sum / c << endl;
break;
}
sum += stof(input);
c++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you cannot check that easily if the `<ENTER>` button has been pressed. `cin` reads formatted input (numbers in your case) and ignores everything else (including whitespaces, like newline). A solution to your problem is to read a whole line and extract the numbers from it:

```
#include <iostream> // cin, cout
#include <sstream> // istringstream
#include <string> // getline

int main()
{
    // Reading a line from the standard input to the variable 'line'.
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // The easiest way to get the numbers from 'line' is to wrap it in an
    // 'istringstream'. Now, you can use 'iss' just like 'cin'.
    std::istringstream iss{line};

    double total = 0.0;
    double counter = 0.0;
    for (double number; iss >> number; ++counter) {
        total += number;
    }
    std::cout << "Avarage: " << total / counter << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer :) I see a little point of improvement: You could calculate the average as floating point calculation (`(double)total / counter`), to avoid truncation of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I totally missed that. Changed to code to use `double`s instead of `int`s.